# vector::clear in libc++ for trivially destructible types

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm, stdvector

Would `vector<T, std::allocator<T>>::clear()` be `O(1)` if `T` is trivially destructible?

gcc's implementation in `bits/stl_vector.h` calls `std::_Destroy`(`bits/stl_construct.h`). This implementation which optimizes for the case of T being trivially destructible through tag-dispatching on `std::is_trivially_destructible<T>`.

Looking through llvm's(3.5.0) implementation, `vector::clear` calls `std::allocator<T>::destroy` on every element, which in turn invokes the destructor.

```
 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void destroy(pointer __p) {__p->~_Tp();}
```

Would this end up getting optimized out making `vector::clear()` `O(1)` in libc++ as well?

Comment: What is the difference between 0 *  N (destruction)  and N * 0 (destruction) ?

Comment: Noticing `destroy` is a noop is easy.  Then we are looping over `vector::clear`, adding to a (local) pointer, doing a comparison to another (local) pointer to terminate, and doing a noop each step.  The compiler may assume that all loops terminate, so it can prune the loop without proving that the loop condition succeeds, and simply assign the looping pointer to the final pointer.  This assignment isn't used.  So I can see a set of steps that would do the optimization.

Comment: @DieterLücking You still have a loop on top. I understand what you are saying though - this seems like a trivial no-op. However, gcc ends up with a tag-dispatched helper. On seeing that implementation, I was unsure about my conclusion that this is a "trivial no-op".

Comment: @Yakk @DieterLücking Perhaps my question really ought to be why gcc bothers with that implementation of `std::_Destroy`. Why would you say that is? Thanks!

Comment: @Pradhan Well, it works in -O0 builds, while the one reliant on optimization does not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, a conforming implementation cannot implement `std::vector::clear` in O(1) for types with non-trivial destructors.

C++11 [container.requirements.general]/3 states:

> For the components affected by this subclause that declare an allocator_type, objects stored in these components shall be constructed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct` function and destroyed using the `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy` function (20.6.8.2).

Since `clear` must destroy `size()` elements, it necessarily needs to make O(N) calls to the `destroy` function of the associated allocator. The end result can, however, effectively take constant time if each of those calls takes zero time to complete (i.e., does nothing).

A quick look at the implementation of `_Destroy` in [the current revision of libstdc++'s bits/stl_construct.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_construct.h?revision=219188&view=markup) shows that it attempts to only perform this optimization when the default allocator is in use:

```
  /**
   * Destroy the object pointed to by a pointer type.
   */
  template<typename _Tp>
    inline void
    _Destroy(_Tp* __pointer)
    { __pointer->~_Tp(); }

  template<bool>
    struct _Destroy_aux
    {
      template<typename _ForwardIterator>
        static void
        __destroy(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
      {
        for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
          std::_Destroy(std::__addressof(*__first));
      }
    };

  template<>
    struct _Destroy_aux<true>
    {
      template<typename _ForwardIterator>
        static void
        __destroy(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator) { }
    };

  /**
   * Destroy a range of objects.  If the value_type of the object has
   * a trivial destructor, the compiler should optimize all of this
   * away, otherwise the objects' destructors must be invoked.
   */
  template<typename _ForwardIterator>
    inline void
    _Destroy(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
    {
      typedef typename iterator_traits<_ForwardIterator>::value_type
                       _Value_type;
      std::_Destroy_aux<__has_trivial_destructor(_Value_type)>::
        __destroy(__first, __last);
    }

  /**
   * Destroy a range of objects using the supplied allocator.  For
   * nondefault allocators we do not optimize away invocation of 
   * destroy() even if _Tp has a trivial destructor.
   */

  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Allocator>
    void
    _Destroy(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
         _Allocator& __alloc)
    {
      typedef __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Allocator> __traits;
      for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        __traits::destroy(__alloc, std::__addressof(*__first));
    }

  template<typename _ForwardIterator, typename _Tp>
    inline void
    _Destroy(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
         allocator<_Tp>&)
    {
      _Destroy(__first, __last);
    }
```

but unfortunately doesn't quite get it right since the standard allows specialization of templates in the `std` namespace that depend on user-defined types ([namespace.std]/1). For example, this program:

```
struct mytype {
    int value;

    mytype(int v) : value{v} {}

    operator int() const { return value; }
};

namespace std {
template <>
struct allocator<::mytype> {
    using value_type = mytype;

    allocator() = default;
    template <typename U>
    allocator(const allocator<U>&) {}

    mytype* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        auto result = ::operator new(n * sizeof(mytype));
        if (!result) throw bad_alloc();
        return static_cast<mytype*>(result);
    }

    void deallocate(mytype* ptr, std::size_t) noexcept {
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }

    template <typename U, typename...Args>
    void construct(U* ptr, Args&&...args) {
        ::new ((void*)ptr) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        std::cout << "constructed " << *ptr << '\n';
    }

    template <typename U>
    void destroy(U* ptr) noexcept {
        std::cout << "destroying " << *ptr << '\n';
        ptr->~U();
    }

    friend constexpr bool operator == (const allocator&, const allocator&) noexcept {
        return true;
    }
    friend constexpr bool operator != (const allocator&, const allocator&) noexcept {
        return false;
    }
};
} // namespace std

int main() {
    std::vector<mytype>{1,2,3};
}
```

should output:

```
constructed 1
constructed 2
constructed 3
destroying 3
destroying 2
destroying 1
```

(the order of element destruction is unspecified, so the "destroying" lines can be in any order but must all be present.) libstdc++ incorrectly "optimizes" out the calls to `allocator<mytype>::construct` and `allocator<mytype>::destroy`, but of course libc++ gets it right ([**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27860e43c400f98e)).

Comment: Just for reference, I've reported this noncomformance as [GCC bug #64865](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64865) despite my belief that it's probably insignificant. I'll let the libstdc++ developers decide for themselves.